# Getting error with Django while requesting any url

Tags: django, centos, django-dev-server

I am running django on django's development server. It was working fine before but from yesterday i keep getting this error on the linux command line where server was running.

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('57.xx.xx.123', 63721)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python27/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 284, in _handle_reque                                                                             st_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "/opt/python27/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 310, in process_reque                                                                             st
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/opt/python27/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 323, in finish_reques                                                                             t
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/opt/python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.p                                                                             y", line 570, in __init__
    BaseHTTPRequestHandler.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/python27/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 641, in __init__
    self.finish()
  File "/opt/python27/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 694, in finish
    self.wfile.flush()
  File "/opt/python27/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 301, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

can anyone guide me that why it started happening now

This happen only 1 out of 10 times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Broken pipe" means that there was still outgoing data on a file descriptor (a socket, in this case) when the destination closed down.

In this case, the most likely cause is the browser closing the connection before the Django development server has sent the entire response.

Answer (score 0):

Occasionally I'll see a broken pipe after an exception, or when connecting to my Linux box form Windows when doing cross-browser/platform testing. I'm not exactly sure what causes these errors, but restarting Django's development server is all I know to do to fix it.